# React Router content not load when refresh forward or manually input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to React and getting familiarize with React Router. I divided the application into 2 main route since each use a different style: the Splash path is when the user first enter which contain the Splashscreen, Login and Register page; the Menu path is shown after the user is logined. Currently I am working on the Splash route but stumble on a few problem. The Splashscreen contain 1 button that go to the Login Screen. When I click on the button it worked fined, but if I refresh the login page, go back to the Spashscreen and forward, or manually enter the address, the page turn out blank. I tried using `HashRouter` and it worked, but some suggested that it should only be used on Dev server and not production. I don't use Webpack so I cannot make `historyApiFallback: true` and the application is running on `localhost`.
Below are my current code:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SplashTemplate from './component/Template/SplashTemplate';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact={true}>
          <SplashTemplate/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

SplashTemplate.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Splash from '../Splash/Splash';
import LoginForm from '../LoginForm/LoginForm';
import RegistrationForm from '../RegistrationForm/RegistrationForm';
import '../Template/SplashTemplate.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function SplashTemplate() {
    return(
        <div className="background">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Splash} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
                    <Route path="/register" component={RegistrationForm}/>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SplashTemplate;
```

Splash.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function Splash() {
    return(
            <div className="container">
                        <Link to="/login">
                            <button className="splashButton">Login</button>
                        </Link>
            </div>
    );
}

export default Splash;
```

Anyone can suggest a solution? I have try the above mention but still not the answer I am looking for.

**Update**
Thanks to Danilo Venticinque answer I have reformatted the `App.js` file to:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <SplashTemplate>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Splash}/>
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm}/>
          <Route path="/register" component={RegistrationForm}/>
        </SplashTemplate>
        <MainTemplate>
          <Route path="/mainmenu" component={MainMenu}/>
        </MainTemplate>
      </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And changed the `SplashTemplate.js` to:

```
class SplashTemplate extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="background">{this.props.children}</div>
        );
    };
}
```

It seem to work for the Splash path but now the problem show up in the Menu path where if the route is input manually (http://localhost:3000/mainmenu) the template for the Menu did not show up but instead the Splash template did. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the  `App.js` routing. It's rendering the `SplashTemplate` component (which contains the other routes) only when the exact path is `/`. So, if you launch the page with `/login`, `SplashTemplate` doesn't get rendered (actually, nothing does) and there's no router to serve your other routes.

I would suggest moving the routes into a single component or changing the `App.js` routing logic so that it would still display `SplashTemplate` for `/login` and other desired routes.

Comment: any suggestion on how to accomplish these? For moving routes into a single component, that mean I define all route in a file and import it to ````App.js````? And for changing the routing logic, I am not sure what do you mean by displaying ````SplashTemplate```` for other desire routes?

Comment: As a short-term solution, replacing the code inside your `App.js` Switch with this:
`<Route exact path="/" component={SplashTemplate} />
 <Route path="/login" component={SplashTemplate} />
 <Route path="/register" component={SplashTemplate}/>`

Should be enough to fix your problem. It would ensure that the `SplashTemplate` is always displayed, and then `SplashTemplate` would be able to display the correct component

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I found another way that seem to work thanks to your previous answer. Now I am facing a similar problem and have updated the question. Can you take a look?

Comment: Your solution will always display the `SplashTemplate` component, so you'll always see the background.

Comment: The routes should be direct children of `Switch`, otherwise you might get unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. I have found my answer after some digging around and combining with the previous iteration. I will put the answer here for other to see.

Answer (score 0):

So after digging around and following both [React Router V4 Routers with Master Pages / Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085464/react-router-v4-routers-with-master-pages-templates) and [React Router v5.0 Nested Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711663/react-router-v5-0-nested-routes) I was able to come up with a solution. First, move all the Routing to a seperate file call `Route.js` and import it to `App.js`. Since we need to seperate the two path we will put the routing in 2 different functions and call them in a main function like below:

**Route.js**

```
...
function LayoutRoute() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/splash" component={SplashLayout} />
        <Route path="/main" component={MainLayout} />
        <Route path="/" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

function SplashLayout() {
    return (
      <SplashTemplate>
            <Route path="/splash/splash" exact component={Splash} />
            <Route path="/splash/login" exact component={LoginForm} />
            <Route path="/splash/register" exact component={RegistrationForm} />
            <Redirect from="/splash" to="/splash/splash" exact />
            <Route />
      </SplashTemplate>
    );
  }

function MainLayout() {
    return (
        <MainTemplate>
            <Route path="/main/menu" exact component={MainMenu} />
            <Redirect from="/main" to="/main/menu" exact />
            <Route />
        </MainTemplate>
        
    );
}

const NotFound = () => <h1>Not Found</h1>;

export default LayoutRoute;
```

The `App.js` can just call Route:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <LayoutRoute></LayoutRoute>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And the Template file:

**SplashTemplate.js**

```
class SplashTemplate extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="background">{this.props.children}</div>
        );
    };
}
```

This can help achive seperated Layout for each path of the website/app needed and make sure the page is rendered when entered manually or refresh.